# Using NLTK getting error: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import pickle as pickle
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
import nltk
import sys

def tokenize(text):
    lmtzr = WordNetLemmatizer()
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    l = []
    for t in tokens:
        try:
            t = float(t)
            l.append("<NUM>")
        except ValueError:
            l.append(lmtzr.lemmatize(t))
    return l

def predict(headline):
    try:
        f = open('trained_model')
        clf = pickle.load(f)
        f = open('vectorizer')
        vectorizer = pickle.load(f)
        return clf.predict_proba(vectorizer.transform(headline))[0][1]
    except IOError:
        print("Model not present, run train.py first")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ("headline is "  + str(int(predict([sys.argv[1]])*100)) + "% likely to be clickbait")
```

my output is :

```
Model not present, run train.py first
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-4fe5d00cb017> in <module>()
     29 
     30 if __name__ == "__main__":
---> 31     print ("headline is "  + str(int(predict([sys.argv[1]])*100)) + "% likely to be clickbait")

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `Model not present, run train.py first` is outputted we know that an `IOError` was raised inside `predict` but the `except` clause just calls `print` which means `predict` will return `None`.

You then do `predict([sys.argv[1]]) * 100)` which means you are trying to do `None * 100` (as the stacktrace suggests) which does not make any sense.

There are several ways to fix this, for example let the exception propagate:

```
def predict(headline):
    f = open('trained_model')
    clf = pickle.load(f)
    f = open('vectorizer')
    vectorizer = pickle.load(f)
    return clf.predict_proba(vectorizer.transform(headline))[0][1]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        print ("headline is "  + str(int(predict([sys.argv[1]])*100)) + "% likely to be clickbait")
    except IOError:
        print("Model not present, run train.py first")
```

or check if its return value is `None` before using it:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    predict_result = predict([sys.argv[1]])
    if predict_result is not None:
        print ("headline is "  + str(int(predict_result * 100)) + "% likely to be clickbait")
```